# Working with private repos on GitHub in Xcode

Tags: xcode, github, swift-package-manager

On our iOS project we have a dependency which is being worked on by another vendor. They will host their code in a private repo and so far I can think of two options.

One, I have to end up manually copying them and set it up in our internal repo which can than be added as a dependency via SPM OR

Two, I have to create a GitHub token and share it with all the team members and ensure they add this account in Xcode to avoid the manual sync.

Both these options are not really great considering that on Android we have a grade script which can work seamlessly.

Is there any other better way to integrate privately hosted SPMs in Xcode ?

Comment: Or you can mirror it somewhere more public to your teammates

Comment: Thanks @MojtabaHosseini ! I was not aware of `git mirror`. That's what I ended up doing. If you can put that as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mirror it somewhere more public to your teammates.